# What is a good way to deal with byte alignment and endianess when packing a struct?

Tags: byte, endianness, memory-alignment

My current design involves communication between an embedded system and PC, where I am always buzzed by the struct design.

The two systems have different endianess that I need to deal with. However, I find that I cannot just do a simple byte-order switch for every 4 bytes to solve the problem. It turns out to depend on the struct.

For example, a struct like this:

```
{
    uint16_t a;
    uint32_t b;
}
```

would result in padding between a and b. Eventually, the endian switch has to be specific to a and b because the existence of the padding bytes. But it looks ugly because I need to change the endian switch logic every time I change the struct content.

What is a good strategy to arrange elements in a struct when padding comes in? Should we try to rearrange the elements so that there is only padding bytes at the end of the struct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll need to do some more platform-neutral serialization, since different architectures have different alignment requirements. I don't think there is a **safe and generic** way to do something like grabbing a chunk of memory and sending it to another architecture where you just place it at some address and read from it (the correct data). Just convert and send the elements one-by-one - you can push the values into a buffer, that will not have any padding and you'll know exactly what is where. Plus you decide which part will do the conversions (typically the PC has more resources to do that). As a bonus you can checksum/sign the communication to catch errors/tampering.

BTW, afaik while the compiler keeps the order of the variables intact, it theoretically can put some additional padding between them (e.g. for performance reasons), so it's not just an architecture related thing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will sending elements one-by-one introduce too much overhead to the communication if the number of elements goes up? But I guess from your opinion, the only alternative is to design a more specific byte-order switch logic?

Comment: That depends a lot on the actual implementation (over what link you are transmitting the data etc.).If you use some kind of buffering then you save on transfer overheads (read on transmission protocol headers) and the code can be easier to read (i.e you'll have functions to serialize and de-serialize the data and a function to do the actual transfer).